# A dot using \pstThreeDDot

Tags: pstricks, 3d, pst-solides3d, pst-3dplot

I want to put a dot on the beginning of the red line. My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pstricks,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(4,6.5)
\psset{unit=1.0cm,viewpoint=50 17 20 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,opacity=0.7,grid}
\axesIIID[showOrigin=false,linewidth=1.5pt,arrowinset=0,arrows=->,arrowscale=1.5,labelsep=15pt](0,0,0)(5,5,5)
\defFunction[algebraic]{line}(t){3*cos(t)}{3*sin(t)}{0}
\psSolid[object=courbe,range=0 1.570796327,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red,
         function=line,r=0,action=draw]
\pstThreeDDot[SphericalCoor,linecolor=red](3,0,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What is wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`pst-solides3d` and `pst-3dplot` are incompatible! The first one is a central projection and the other one a parallel projection. Use

```
\psSolid[object=point,linecolor=red,args=3 0 0]
```

[image]

or rotate the 3d coordinate system also for `pst-3dplot`. `viewpoint` is not valid for `pstThreeDDot`

Comment: Many thanks, Herbert. I'm now using \psSolid[object=line,linecolor=red,args=3 0 0 3 3 0] to joint two points by a straight line but I also want to put arrows in the end of the line. How can I do it?

Comment: `pst-solides3d` has only 3d arrows: `\psSolid[object=vecteur, args=1 2 2]` For 2d arrows set first two 3d nodes and then `\psline{<->}(A)(B)`

Comment: Ok. Just one last question: I’m also trying to plot vector fields in the plane, namely the vector field $F(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{2}x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \mathbf{i} + \frac{\sqrt{2}y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \mathbf{j}$. I used \psVectorfield but I don’t know very well how this command works (the pst-plot-doc pdf manual does not tell much about it). I also know that tikz package is an alternative...

Comment: ... The problem is I have some other figures in the same picture using PSTricks and I don’t want to convert them to tikz. I’m also aware of the link http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi but the example presented there (http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples#vector) is not simple... what do you suggest to plot vector fields? There any command in PSTricks? e.g. like “fieldplot” in Maple?

Comment: `\pstVectorfield` is a simple 2d vector filed of a given `z=f(x,y)` and should be easy to use.

Comment: Ok, but for the referred vector field what is putted in “{ }”, i.e. 
\psVectorfield (-1.9,-1.9)(1.9,1.9){?}

Comment: The function z=f(x,y)as can be seen in the example in the doc of pst- plot